# How to use JavaScript as an embedded resource in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, resources

I have two projects. One is basically a class library in which I want to list all the Javascripts and call those Javascript from the second project which is basically a Asp.Net MVC project.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: I think you need to add more detail about what you want exactly. what's your problem?

Comment: I can understand what you want but not understand what its benefit is. Looks like you want to reuse the javascript package (of your own), in that case we can publish the package and later install it in each project that need it. By embedding the js files as resource like what you want, each time starting the web app, it should check all the embedded files to see if they have been extracted and copied to some wwwroot folder. If they are copied, just do nothing, otherwise you must perform the resource extraction